# jQuery show and hide forms on click next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set of forms and only one form is shown at a time. once a user has filled the form and click on next the current form will hide and the next form will show. and also there's a back button in order to traverse back through forms if user needs to amend any fields. I think the approach I have taken is not quite right. Hence need your assistance.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fd0839nL/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-continue').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.forms-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
    $(this).parents('.forms-wrapper').next('.forms-wrapper').removeClass('d-none');
  });
});
```

```css
.col-centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
      <div class="forms-wrapper mb-5">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-4">Back</a>
        <p>Form 1</p>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <a class="btn btn-primary form-continue">Next Form</a>
        </form>
      </div>


      <div class="forms-wrapper mb-5 d-none">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-4">Back</a>
        <p>Form 2</p>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <a class="btn btn-primary form-continue">Next Form</a>
        </form>
      </div>


      <div class="forms-wrapper d-none">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-4">Back</a>
        <p>Form 3</p>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <a class="btn btn-primary form-continue">Finish</a>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I would like to see a better approach from jQuery.

Comment: You can use jQuery's `show` and `hide` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code snippet to understand the functionality. You can also add validations as per your requirement.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".divs div").each(function (e) {
                if (e != 0)
                    $(this).hide();
            });

            $("#next").click(function () {
                if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
                    $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
                else {
                    $(".divs div:visible").hide();
                    $(".divs div:first").show();
                }
                return false;
            });

            $("#prev").click(function () {
                if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
                    $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
                else {
                    $(".divs div:visible").hide();
                    $(".divs div:last").show();
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    
    
     <div class="divs">
     <div class="cls1">
         <p>Form 1</p>
         <form>
         
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            
         </form>
     </div>
     <div class="cls2">
         <p>Form 2</p>
         <form>
             
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            
           
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
            
         </form>
     </div>
     <div class="cls3">
         <p>Form 3</p>
         <form>
            
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
             
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
            
         </form>
     </div>
     
 </div>
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next"  />
<input type="button" id="prev" value="Previous"  />
```

For more details refer [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064433/show-hide-divs-using-next-previous-button-using-jquery)

Comment: This does the job for me, In addition one more question. How could I focus on the first input of each form when I click the next button?

Comment: Dont forget to up vote and mark it as a correct answer :P 
You can use `$(":input:first").focus();` to get it done. refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026091/jquery-dynamically-focus-on-the-first-input-or-textarea)